# system of equations with an odd number of distinct solutions, with absolute value sign

Tags: systems-of-equations, absolute-value

Suppose that $a$ is a number such that the system of equations

$|2x| − y = 5$

$x − |2y + 2| = a$

has an odd number of distinct solutions. What is the product of all possible values of $a$?

This is a middle-school level math problem, I searched it but couldn't find a solution. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To have an odd number of solutions, either $2x$ or $2y+2$ has to be zero.